# Ubuntu 20.04 - Small Cursor in some applications - 4k Screen with 200% Scaling

Tags: 20.04, cursor, scaling, 4k-monitor

Update: I've narrowed this down to Ubuntu on Wayland, running without Wayland my cursor is the correct size across all applications. I still don't have a solution but I'm closer than before.

Original:
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and having an issue with the mouse cursor being different sizes (normal size or tiny) depending on the application I'm hovering over on my Laptop screen. The External monitor shows the cursor in the correct size in all applications.

I'm assuming it's related to the scaling but I'm stumped as how to fix the issue.

**My Setup**

Ubuntu 20.04 - Wayland

Dell XPS 7390 - 4K Screen using 200% scaling in Display Settings

External Monitor - 3840x1200 using 100% scaling in Display Settings

When I move from one window to the other the mouse cursor will either stay the same size or shrink to a tiny size depending on the application, examples below.

**Normal Size Cursor**

Desktop, Firefox, VS Code, LibreOffice

**Tiny Cursor**

Terminal, Nautilus, Ubuntu Settings

Answer (score 5):

After months of trying to track it down I found opening Gnome Tweaks and setting a new Theme & picking different Cursor and Icons settings resolved the issue.

Gnome Tweaks -> Appearance -> Themes
Set
Applications
Cursor
Icons

And problem is gone

Comment: Didn't work for me unforturnately. Default cursor changed though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

What fixed it for me was:
Go into:

settings->accessibility->cursor size

And then change it to something really big. It should change directly, but did not for me (nothing happened, but leave it like that). Eventually the setting did take effect, but the scaling was still different on the different applications. When I changed it back to normal size though, it got the same size everywhere and immediately.

Bonkers.

I suppose some setting was not correctly migrated in the upgrade from 18.04.

Comment: Hi, I tried the suggestion but nothing changed unfortunately, I've still got a tiny cursor in most Ubuntu specific windows.

Comment: This most likely will not fix the issue for users with scaled screen resolutions. Setting a cursor theme in tweaks should work.